# Catching webdriver disconnection issue and processing extra activities

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using the new selenium webdriver and everything is mostly great, but if connection issues occur and the browser either closes without my directing, or various other reasons, I get an error reading as follows: -

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

In these situations I'd like to catch it and call some code to run updates against tables etc to inform the user that this has happened, how would I do this?

I have tried to be clever and run this off of a database of "actions" the code basically runs through these actions in sequence using a great big "if action = XYZ call blah" list like so"

```
if (actionType.equals("NAVIGATETO")){
        actionPassed = threadAction.NavigateTo(this);
    }
    else if(actionType.equals("TYPE")){
        actionPassed = threadAction.Type(this);
    }
    else if(actionType.equals("CLOSEBROWSER")){
        actionPassed = threadAction.CloseBrowser(this);
    }...
```

Would I need to wrap each in a try and catch?  Or would I need to implement the try and catch at the next level down in each of the actions?  Here's an example of an action...

```
public boolean browserNav(individualThreadSession threadsesh){

if(threadsesh.stringValue.contains("BACK")){
            threadsesh.driver.navigate().back();
        }
        else if(threadsesh.stringValue.contains("REFRESH")){
            threadsesh.driver.navigate().refresh();
        }
        else if(threadsesh.stringValue.contains("GOTO")){
            threadsesh.driver.navigate().to(threadsesh.stringValue);
        }
        return(true);
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions, I really have no idea where to even start on this idea?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

If you are using JUnit to execute, you can extend the TestWatcher class:

```
public class TestRules extends TestWatcher {

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        // This will be called whenever a test fails.
    }
```

So in your test class you can simply call it:

```
public class testClass{

@Rule
public TestRules testRules = new TestRules();

@Test
public void doTestSomething() throws Exception{
    // If the test fails for any reason, it will be caught be testrules.
}
```

**Solution 2**
Take a look into [EventFiringWebDriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html). You can attach [WebDriverEventListener](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html#onException%28java.lang.Throwable,%20org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver%29) to it and override the onException method.

Something like:

```
EventFiringWebDriver driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new FirefoxDriver());
WebDriverEventListener listener = new AbstractWebDriverEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable t, WebDriver driver) {
        // Take action
    }
};
driver.register(listener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not using Junit to run my application, I'm either just running it from selenium, or once its stabilised, I'm just exporting it into a runnable jar file...  Any suggestions in this situation?

Comment: I've tried to implement this but when I put in the line `driver.register(listener);` I am told by eclipse that `The method register(WebDriverEventListener) is undefined for the type WebDriver` is it because earlier on I have the line reading `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),capability);`

Comment: I tried changing my code to the following but same issue   `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),capability);`   
`driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);`   
`driver.register(listener);`

Comment: Thanks for the link I shall check all that out!  I also tried what Eclipse suggested and ended up with the following, which seems to work!  Cheers! :) `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),capability);
   driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
   ((EventFiringWebDriver) driver).register(listener);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QAF selenium testing framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) - [QAF formerly ISFW](http://blog.infostretch.com/isfw-faq) and provide implementation of onFailure in WebDriverListener